# How to determine size of a Linked List without using a while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop, linked-list, size

I need to print out the number of nodes in a linked list. My teacher said that the linked list keeps track of its data and "knows" how many nodes are in it. So, I should not need a while loop to determine the size of the linked list. I have trouble figuring out a way other than a while loop to print out the size.

this is the linked list:

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
struct ListNode
{
  T data ;
  struct ListNode * next;
};

ListNode *head;

public:
LinkedList() { head = nullptr; }
 ~LinkedList();

// Linked list operations
void insertNode(T);
bool deleteNode(T);
void displayList() const;
};


/////////// Implementation portion of linked list with template  //////////////

// displayList: print all list data
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::displayList() const
{
ListNode * ptr = head;

while (ptr != nullptr)
{
    cout << ptr->data << endl;
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
}

// insertNode: add a node in list order
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertNode(T newValue)
{
ListNode *newNode;
ListNode *pCur;
ListNode *pPre = NULL;

newNode = new ListNode;
newNode->data = newValue;
newNode->next = nullptr;

if (head == nullptr)
{
  head = newNode;
}
else
{
    pCur = head;
    pPre = nullptr;
    while (pCur != nullptr && pCur->data < newValue)
    {
        pPre = pCur;
        pCur = pCur->next;
    }

    if (pPre == nullptr)
    {
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = pCur;
    }
    else
    {
        pPre->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = pCur;
    }
}
}

// deleteNode: delete a node if found
template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::deleteNode(T toBeDeleted)
{
ListNode *pCur;
ListNode *pPre;

if (!head)
    return true;

pCur = head;
pPre = NULL;
while (pCur != NULL && pCur->data < toBeDeleted)
{
     pPre = pCur;
     pCur = pCur->next;
}

if (pCur != NULL && pCur->data == toBeDeleted)
{
    if (pPre)
        pPre->next = pCur->next;
    else
        head = pCur->next;
    delete pCur;
    return true;
}
return false;
}


// destructor, delete all nodes
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
ListNode *ptr = head;
while (ptr != NULL)
{
    head = head->next;
    delete ptr;
    ptr = head;
}
}
```

Comment: It depends how your linked list is implemented. If it keeps track of the number of nodes, then you don't need to loop. It it doesn't, then you have no choice but to loop through all nodes. As you don't show the implementation, we cannot provide an answer.

Comment: One option would be to somehow store a counting number on each node.  Then you would just need access to the tail to find out how many nodes there are.  But this would complicate operations such as add and remove.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What your teacher said only applies to some specific implementation he has in mind. There are many that don't behave that way. You need to ask him what implementation he's talking about, or review your lecture notes if he's already told you.

Comment: If the list "knows" how many nodes it contains, the answer is to ask it how many nodes it contains.

Comment: @juanchopanza how can I ask? is there a size command?

Comment: How do you expect me to know if there is a size command? Please, think about what you are asking here.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm sorry if i ask stupid questions. This is my first time learning about linked lists. Let me put it this way: can I use .size() or sizeof() to determine size of the linked list?

Comment: If you are talking about a `std::list` say so (or even better: look up the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) yourself). If it is some other linked list, how are we supposed to help you / know what member functions it has, if we don't know anything about it? `sizeof` will almost certainly not work

Comment: @A.G. please tell us more about the _specific_ linked list you are talking about.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I edited my question.

Comment: @A.G. this implementatrion doesn't keep track of the number of nodes. So you have to loop through the whole list. If ylou don't want this, you must mofify the code.

Answer (score 1):

Using the code you've defined, the size of the list is not stored by the list directly. Further to this, the main advantage of linked list is that each node does not know about the rest of the list, and storing the size would defeat the purpose of this.

However, you may have misunderstood what was asked of you in terms of not using a `while` loop. Each node knows that it's length is 1+(the length of it's tail), and so the more suitable implementation for getting the length of a linked list is recursion, not iteration.

Here is an example of a very simple LinkedList class, that implements the simple methods using recursion. As you can see, the code uses no iteration, only making a check for it's own data, then calling the same method for the next node. Although recursion in procedural languages is less efficient in most cases, for structures like this there is no doubting it is elegant.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    T data;
    LinkedList* next;
public:
    LinkedList()
        : LinkedList(T()) {
    }
    LinkedList(T value)
        : data(value), next(nullptr) {
    }
    ~LinkedList() {
        delete next;
    }

    void insertNode(T newValue) {
        if (!next) {
            next = new LinkedList(newValue);
            return;
        }

        next->insertNode(newValue);
    }

    void displayList() const {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
        if (next) {
            next->displayList();
        }
    }

    T& at(int N) {
        if (N == 0) {
            return this->data;
        }
        return next->at(N-1);
    }

    int size() {
        if (!next) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 1+next->size();
    }
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    LinkedList<int>* test = new LinkedList<int>(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        test->insertNode(i);
    }

    std::cout << "List of length: " << test->size() << std::endl;
    test->displayList();

    return 0;
}
```

You'll notice I haven't included `deleteNode`, that's because writing it for the oversimplified class above is not possible for the case where the list only has one node. One possible way to implement this is to have a wrapper class, much like you in the original code, that is a pointer to the start of a linked list. See [here](http://pad.mattdiesel.co.uk/simple-linkedlist).

Comment: It is true that recursion can be used to find the length of the linked list, thus avoiding a while loop, but recursion is actually a kind of loop and it is even less efficient than a straight loop.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, as mentioned in the answer, yes it is typically less efficient in procedural languages. The OP said "I have trouble figuring out a way other than a while loop to print out the size." and so I gave the only sensible answer there is. As I also said, a linked list with the length stored in a node kindof defeats the purpose of a linked list, though could be done easily enough in the wrapper class I link to.

Comment: the link is now broken